# Regex.Matches match uppercase and lowercase

Tags: .net, regex

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "X"))
{
      indexes.Add(match.Index);
}
```

I have a quick question. Here is my part of code, and I'm getting indexes of X's, but I also want to get indexes even if X's is in lowercase. What should I write?

Comment: You should write `"[Xx]"`. This is covered by *any* regex tutorial, reading one of which is IMHO a reasonable step before asking on SO if you are going to be using regexes.

Comment: If you're only looking for a single character then using a Regex is a heavyweight solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `i` mode modifier (make the regular expression case-insensitive):

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "(?i)X"))
```

or use [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "X", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

or specify both `X` and `x`:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "[Xx]"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using regex you could just do `Regex.Matches(line.ToLower(), 'x')`.

Comment: Though a solution, it's quite inefficient because the Regex match is now an O(2n) operation with the `ToLower`.

Comment: Is Regex matching not O(n) anyway (honest question, I have no clue)? I wasn't considering performance here, by the way :)

Comment: A Regex is not an O(n) operation by definition, but rather greatly depends on the expression itself.

Comment: I misspoke in text but was thinking along another line, it's an `O(2n)` operation with the `ToLower`.

Comment: I would have thought it would be O(n) as you would have to traverse the string to find the pattern, surely. Thanks for clarification though.